# How to fix this code to copy values into columns?

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever the value in cell B2 of sheet1 changes, value is copied and pasted into sheet2 column A in the next blank cell.
I need to change this to paste the values into ROW 2 ie, A2,B2,C2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
a = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & a).Value = 
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `I need to change this to paste the values into ROW 2 ie, A2,B2,C2` So what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this answer for the request in the comments.

You'll first want to create a sheet - can be a hidden sheet - this code will do it for you, but feel free to manually do it.

```
Sub Create_Hidden_Control_sheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    ws.Name = "Control"

    ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    ws.Range("A1") = "Last cell used"
    ws.Range("B1") = 0

End Sub
```

You'll use the cell B1 on this sheet to store the last column used.

You'll want to change your worksheet_change to do something along the lines of this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim a As Integer

If Target.Address = "$B$2" And Target.Value > 0 Then

    a = Sheets("Control").Range("B1") + 1

    If a > 10 Then
        a = 1
    End If

    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, a) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value

    Sheets("Control").Range("B1") = a

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim v_target_row As Integer

If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then

    v_target_row = 2

    If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(v_target_row, 1) = "" Then
        a = 0
    Else
        a = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(v_target_row, Sheets("Sheet2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(v_target_row, a + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thousands of Thanks. Great.

Comment: How can I change that code to copy and paste only if the value changed is greater than Zero.

Comment: You will want to add in Target.Value > 0 to either the original IF statement or create a new one

Comment: Thanks mickeyD.  Sorry to bother you further.  How can I loop this code for a range of cell values in same Column B,  ie B2 to B200.  Once again Thanks. I am new to this Vba coding.

Comment: You'd want to take a different approach for this. As your spreadsheet will likely open/close several times, you'd need to store your last value on a separate sheet [or you can do a text file] - I'll add another answer with some code for you